# Doctrine : Foreign keys are not generated

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The problem I have with doctrine is that after the

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

it creates the DB but not the foreign keys.
I'm using annotations and I tried to use the @ORM\JoinColumn in the ManyToOne ... etc annotations but without success.

I hope you guys can help me.

Here is the code of one of my entities:

```
<?PHP

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="member")
 */
class Member{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=25)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=25)
 */
private $first_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=25)
 */
private $last_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $national_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=25)
 */
private $civil_situation;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=1)
 */
private $gender;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $dob;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $tel_mobile;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $tel_home;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $tel_ref;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=25)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $entry_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer",nullable=true)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Staff")
 */
private $staff;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer",nullable=true)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Student")
 */
private $student;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Faculty")
 */
private $faculty;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $disable;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=25,nullable=true)
 */
private $disable_reason;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer",nullable=true)
 */
private $disable_year;

public function __construct()
{
    //nothing
}

// getters and setters

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `@ORM\Column` is specified along with `@ORM\JoinColumn` on same column, then JoinColumn's association gets ignored and Foreign Key isn't created on table. so dont use both `@ORM\Column` and `@ORM\JoinColumn` in same column.

Do like below:

```
/**
*  @var Address
*
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
*/
private $address;
```

It makes column named `address_id` on database table, with foreign key index and on deletion of Address record, associated record in dependent table is also deleted(cascade operation). You may user other operation on onDelete, see doctrine's documentation.

Comment: @Lothair You don't need to specify data type for associations, doctrine handles it and assign data type based on database engine. For MySql, it's int. Does my soln fixed it? please upvote if it fixed. And please also remove these answers that you posted as they are not answers.

Comment: Oh okay I didn't knew about that. I'm currently editing all of my entities docs so I'll tell you if it worked when I finish

Comment: It worked so far but I only have one that isn't working, I post the code bellow aswell as the error given :

Comment: the code : http://i.imgur.com/wQkxpmI.png and the error : http://i.imgur.com/lsRHmGI.png

Comment: Where else have u used `item_code`, it should not be anywhere except that annotation. Use --verbose for details when using schema:update command.

Comment: Ah I used it in others anotations too, so it must be unique ? The solution should be for each annotation a different name ? But I don't understand why I have the error only for this one then, because I used     member_code     in others annotations too

Comment: That's the name given to column in the table on your database. Two column names in same table cannot be same. Please upvote answer if it fixed error so that i can comment on other's post. and please read doctrine documentation.

Comment: Okay I understood, the column had its name to item and not item_code so that's why it wasn't working, I thought with the update --force it would have changed the column's name. Thank you it's working now. For the upvote it's telling me it's been taken in consideration but it's not showed up, anyway I'll close the topic, thank you again